# How do I show the wait cursor WITH the arrow?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, cursor

I've got a long running task that I'm launching with `await Task.Run`. While my task runs, I'd like to show the wait cursor, but the one which also has the arrow. This arrow doesn't exist explicitly in the CursorType enumeration. According to Wikipedia, the normal wait cursor "can be accompanied by an arrow if the operation is being performed in the background." How do I take advantage of this. If I use `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait` from the UI thread, I get the normal wait cursor. If I try setting it from my background thread, I get an error. If I use `Dispatcher.Invoke`, I'm right back to calling it from my UI thread.

Comment: why do you want a busy arrow? the Task is to give the user a feeling of smoothly running

Comment: I'd like to give a visual indication that, yes, the chosen task is processing but the gui can still be used in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It's the `AppStarting` cursor that I'm looking for. Seems like the Wikipedia article was leading me down the wrong road. Who would have though? :D